# Django Templates Display The Latest 3 Comments

Tags: python, django, for-loop, if-statement

I have this code in django that, for every django comment, does whatever is inside the for loop:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all %}

{% endfor %}
```

This code, for every comment, does whatever is inside the for. To count the comments I use this:

```
{{ post.comments.count }}
```

This is my comment model in case you need it:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Now, I want to sort of combine these together, so it shows only the latest 3 comments and only runs the for loop 3 times or less. (Please note that I want to do all of this work in the templates, and not in the views.py file)

Comment: Can you share your comment model? Are the comments ordered by default by the publication date?

Comment: Sure, I'll share it. And yes, the comments are ordered by publication date.

Comment: you should do it in the views. this isn't performant. for a quick template solution you could try `{% for comment in post.comments.all|slice:":3" %}`

Comment: @hansTheFranz, Yeah I know I should probably be doing it in the views.py file but I have a few reasons why I can't put it in the views file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the comments by default by the creation date with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        'blog.Post',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='comments'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_date']

    # …
```

Then you can work with the [**`|slice`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) to slice the queryset:

```
{% for comment in post.comments.all|slice:':3' %}

{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

It is however better to prefetch the elements in the view, with:

```
Post.objects.prefetch_related('comments')
```

this will fetch the comments in *bulk*, which is more efficient than running a query *per* `Post` object.